# Widget adjustment in QT without using layouts

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am working in Qt 5.7 in C++ in QT Designer. In **central widget** I have two labels fulfilled with pictures. One picture is big (*label*), second is smaller, smaller (*label_2*) is in front of the bigger one. When I resize the **MainWindow**, the pictures are not adjusting its size. I was trying to adjust them using **layouts**, but my problem is that the smaller picture must overlay the bigger one (map and map position). And when I use layout, pictures are always put in a different place. How to force picture in the labels (*label, label_2*) adjusting its size depending on Main Windows without using a layout?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `QLabel::setScaledContents()` to scale pictures with layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the resize events of the main window and set the labels geometry accordingly.

In this case, I suggest to reimplement the `resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)` in the implementation of the widget created by the designer, to handle the resize events.

Example:

```
void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
   QMainWindow::resizeEvent(event);
   int x1, y1, w1, h1;
   int x2, y2, w2, h2;
   // compute the labels geometry
   // you can get the old and the new window size
   // calling event->oldSize() and event->size()
   //....
   label->setGeometry(x1, y2, w1, h1);
   label_2->setGeometry(x2, y2, w2, h2);
}
```

See [QWidget::resizeEvent()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#resizeEvent)